# How to spawn another main()?

Tags: java, spawn

Is it possible to run one `main()` application from another as if it was ran from the command prompt?

I know I can use `Runtime.exec()` but if it is possible to run from pure java?

**UPDATE**

If I just run `main()` by calling it, it will run in the same thread and the caller will wait until it finished. If I run main in new thread it may interfere with caller via static members.

My goal is to run entirely separate application.

Comment: can you elobarate "thread may interfere with caller via static members"

Comment: Do you want the 2 main to run on the same process? Why don't you want to use `Runtime.exec()`?

Comment: You might be able to avoid conflict of static class members by instantiating a new classloader for the second application. Not sure how well that would work, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want a separate application, then there's no way around `Runtime.exec()` or equivalent. Process spawning is a function of the operating system, and Java must invoke the operating system's execution method somehow.

You can, however, uses classloaders and threads to execute two applications within the same JVM. The most common use case is an application server, but you can use a container such as [Plexus](http://plexus.codehaus.org/) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate a new `Thread` and inside it's run method call the `main()` method of the another class.

Answer (score 1):

Main is static function you can call it from any other function and should run fine.

Comment: It will wait for callee termination. This is not the spawning.